# How to properly map deep nested keys to their values with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm building a form library, and I need to restrict assignments of some field descriptors based on their values. I want the user to provide the form state and an optional object, adding additional meta information for some fields.
The user must be able to target nested fields in the form state. To achieve that, I'm using @clickbar/dot-diver.

Those are the types:

```
import type { Path, PathValue } from '@clickbar/dot-diver'

// the form meta description
type FormField<VALUE> = { initialValue: VALUE }

// the mapped type narrowing nested fields and values
type MatchFormField<STATE> = { [FIELD in Path<STATE>]-?: FormField<PathValue<STATE, FIELD>> }
```

Everything works fine with the types I have if I use them directly.

```
const data = {
  name: 'matteo',
  profile: {
    preferences: {
      fruits: ['apple', 'peach'],
    }
  }
}

type FormState = Partial<MatchFormField<typeof data>>

export const form: FormState = {
  name: { initialValue: 'matteo' },
  'profile.preferences.fruits': {
    initialValue: ['apple', 'peach'],
  },

  // this is correctly marked as invalid
  unknownField: { initialValue: 'matteo' }, 
}
```

Once I move the types into type generics, the type broadens too much, allowing any unknown value.

```
export type FormConfig<
  STATE,
  FIELDS extends Partial<MatchFormField<STATE>>,
> = {
  id: string
  initialValues: STATE
  fields?: FIELDS
}

declare function createForm<
  STATE,
  FIELDS extends Partial<MatchFormField<STATE>>,
>(config: FormConfig<STATE, FIELDS>): void

createForm({
  id: 'test-form',
  initialValues: {
    uid: 'abcd',
    profile: {
      name: 'Mark',
      age: 44,
    }
  },
  fields: {
    uid: { initialValue: '00000' },
    'profile.age': { initialValue: 99 },

    // this should be marked as invalid, but is not
    unknownField: { initialValue: 'matteo' }, 
  },
})
```

What am I missing?.

You can test it in the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&pretty=true&noErrorTruncation=true&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nACgQxgCwBps98A1HAGwFc0BfOAMyghDgHIABAY0uG4DWAIxxQA9ABMIMALQTgANxRR2AWABQGpKjgAxaCF3AUlCQB4yAQQAyAVQCiAPjgBeDBrhxgAO2AxgVBQ0KABccFZ29hp0GlrIaACyeNz4+lCGxqZmAMoAKpa5Tq4YcADaugCS9tYAIl7eJAQ5+YWOALoyAPxhaRkm5rgEQbTNBfbEldU1js4xmurcEN4AzvASeDjF6B5w3jggoRwgeDAoEOyEO2AsjMCUh9vqnp7XKIzKKN7cKMthj8-PZjUPy-MrsHBgMD3C4cVA4FLsNqXJ7POaeOZzbRoXrZGB4NBuXCwAKUMxJGApXpGfpmLEQRhwdZ4mYaFAAD0gsDgixW8EYBh6Blx+K2Oz2Bz+9T8JOGh3Yxxgp3OcDoyM87Gu9LuKAAdK93lBPt9ljqgSD2H8dp4fNLAlRaGFSuDIdDiBqUPD8Ii1SqfdRvAJvBAAO7eammSU2-x24JheUnM7sX1wMRiODLfAQaimJg4O7RWLqdmc+BYvQGADCS1uAHMzDs8mMfZNatk4OzTt4JMsSMSqGTkqkDOHzI3Wo5kc43P8vBIwqsoD4azsozL7T8wmOoijbv1lt09FVWwX5hIULxRGhGP7uP4ltzDfjevWUVvm0eam2O59u73o6TyUpYdMlHFonAnDRHAACh5WtBXSKtvFrUZCgmD9skcABKMIFAgYAJELbhH1OXooJnfC4wuFdfH-WVQRnTxxTlBUlSolFPHhRZ-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-iivmAEZoIYAe3a7Mpp8uBjglya4BwHsqpq4nVYDINQxHM3WeYhNlSCnZFfUOgyfUIA)

Comment: Don't know why you would say that that last example should be marked as invalid. That `fields` object satisfies your `FIELDS extends Partial<MatchFormField<STATE>>` rule. As per your type definition, it's valid.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you don't get enough engagement here, please consider [edit]ing the question to remove the dependency on "@clickbar/dot-diver" so that the code is a self-contained [mre] that only requires native TS code to investigate.  That might mean building a toy example that has the same problem.

Comment: Thank you @RobbyCornelissen! That is so obvious now that you pointed it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RobbyCornelissen, I have got a working solution.
The issue is how I defined the generic type.

Changing `createForm` like that respects the type of narrowing I need:

```
export type FormConfig<STATE> = {
  id: string
  initialValues: Partial<MatchFormField<STATE>>
  fields?: FIELDS
}

declare function createForm<STATE>(config: FormConfig<STATE>): void
```

This is the [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&pretty=true&noErrorTruncation=true&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nACgQxgCwBps98A1HAGwFc0BfOAMyghDgHIABAY0uG4DWAIxxQA9ABMIMALQTgANxRR2AWABQGpKjgAxaCF3AUlCQB4yAQQAyAVQCiAPjgBeDBrhxgAO2AxgVBQ0KABccFZ29hp0GlrIaACyeNz4%20lCGxqZmAMoAKpa5Tq4YcADaugCS9tYAIl7eJAQ5%20YWOALoyAPxhaRkm5rgEQbTNBfbEldU1js4xmurcEN4AzvASeDjF6B5w3jggoRwgeDAoEOyEO2AsjMCUh9vqnp7XKIzKKN7cKMthj8-PZjUPy-MrsHBgMD3C4cVA4FLsNqXJ7POaeOZzbRoXrZGB4NBuXCwAKUMxJGApXpGfpmLEQRhwdZ4mYaFAAD0gsDgixW8EYBh6Blx%20K2Oz2Bz%209T8JOGh3Yxxgp3OcDoyM87Gu9LuKAAdK93lBPt9ljqgSD2H8dp4fNLAlRaGFSuDIdDiBqUPD8Ii1SqfdRvAJvBAAO7eammSU2-x24JheUnM7sX1wMRiODLfAQaimJg4O7RWLqdmc%20BYvQGADCS1uAHNRoUJlVatlnG5-l4JGFVlAfDWdlGZfafmE8mMdrd%20stunomzVsgX5hIULxRGhGP7uP4ltzDfjevWnAAKHm1wXpKveWsH4hE6Ok8mUgzh8yj1ozACUYQUEGAEkL3F3U5ekPdtfzjC5%2018O9ZVBdtPHFOUFSVCCUU8eFFn9GAwgATlwvCfReG5tUtVDnhwGtDgAFkogjngw7wYCgRA4wqPFKEQFCAUIt4Pi%20Yd3FIgEzRgUEnQhKEUBhd1PW9K0uLxGtRMwMCOBwGFKBwIQTDjJIfCTVUShU9ghHUzTtI4AB5AhlH04hlM7DhuFMrTKDjbJWEklUkTk9E5LRX1x0yCRYLkgAiHwFCoX9QsjKDB1jDhbJTNMMyzHNGDzSg5NTOBQoQmLDLimMHTgf0l1ubwUAkZMcsWKBDU3djc3zUjQs1W57h1ejGMQArlKKyhZTjWxsksJKcsivhqueML2u1PVDQNI0flNKBgREnUAAY%20qlaChzjSrgzgDSXPGtNJt-WaiM6-VeONHUFJNABGHUTpMHaB2KuVDuOszKH05K4Auv8UQxd9-0AlBgNAhz2FOVYZH5dJON2%20LaBC0jgVhzTuAkFHCK1e4SK43Z9jlJIoAEfGyIosJqNo-zVUCydieeLHYttQb9o4Tbed52y5I1a7dXIySOb2hLcIC%20YARyghgGWdNM2zaqtLgY5KaquAcEViKopBgF-UDEMwyC8W0cQhNlSZ0HkTocH1CAA) to the updated playground.